# Element offsetTop is not changing when in a scrolling container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to detect when an element appears out of the bounds of a container through use of the `offsetTop` property, but the property is not giving the results I would expect. See [this simplified JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zx9ad07j/4/) for context.

The definition of the `offsetTop` property according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop):

> The HTMLElement.offsetTop read-only property returns the distance of the outer border of the current element relative to the inner border of the top of the offsetParent, the closest positioned ancestor element.

In my JSFiddle example, you can see that the offset parent for the `#target` element is `#container`, as expected since it's the nearest positioned ancestor. I would then expect that when scrolling `#container`, the value of `target.offsetTop` would change, as the distance from `#target` to the top of `#container` – its offset parent – is now changing. However, that is not the case as `target.offsetTop` does not change at all when the container is scrolled. (I made sure that the text in the example is being updated on scroll)

Am I understanding this property wrong? Or have I done something that causes it to work differently than as defined?

---

**Edit:** I was indeed understanding it wrong as the MDN docs are (in my opinion) misleading at the time of writing. The MDN docs state that `offsetTop` is relative to the "inner border of the top of the offsetParent". However, the [CSS spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsettop) more accurately states that the calculation is done relative to the **padding-edge** of the offset parent – not its border-edge as would be implied by the MDN definition.

Comment: You want to use `IntersectionObserver`, not `onScroll` event.

Comment: Interesting I hadn't heard of that before, I will use that instead thank you! Although I'd still like to know why `offsetTop` isn't working as I'd expect 

Comment: And yes, you understand `offsetTop` property wrong. When a container is scrollable, you'd deal with `scrollHeight` and `scrollTop` properties as well. Offset position would not change, scroll position would.

Comment: That makes sense but for the sake of understanding, why does `offsetTop` not update when scrolling, when MDN states that it's relative to the "inner border of the top of the offsetParent"? Does the "inner border" refer to something other than the element's actual border?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not responsible for MDN statement =)), it may be incomplete. The [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsettop) has it more detailed (see the `initial containing block` term).

Comment: Haha totally fair, the spec does explain what's going on though thank you! The spec more accurately states that the calculation is done relative to the **padding-edge** of the offset parent – not its border-edge as would be implied by the MDN definition.

Comment: This might not be helpful, but [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) might be useful in your case

Comment: @epiqu1n Why not post your findings as a self-answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child's `offsetTop` will remain consistent while the parent scrolls, but the parent's `scrollTop` will update to reflect the number of pixels the parent is scrolled vertically. A simple way to achieve the desired behavior is to subtract the child's `offsetTop` from the parent's `scrollTop`.

See this updated codepen as an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/08Ltchb9/

Comment: If you brought the code from the jsfiddle into a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) this might be a better answer...